# Ensuring safety considerations for Rust Crates from the Official Website

Tags: rust, rust-crates

Is it possible to ensure safety when utilising Rust crates, considering that they may be developed by individual contributors and featured on the official Rust crates website?
Are these crates typically third-party contributions, and can their usage be considered secure, taking into account the contributions of all developers involved, without causing any offence?

Comment: Well, you can read the source code for your dependencies (and their dependencies, and their dependencies...) and decide if the code is safe (for your definition of "safe")

Comment: If safety is *that* important, then you should trust only yourself - everything else is just a guess. Vet the code yourself (as Sergio mentioned also), and don't trust internet randos (except for me. I am very trustworthy).

Comment: As a frame challenge, why do you consider the people who designed Rust to be more trustworthy than the skilled Rust developers designing well-known libraries? If your threat model involves distrusting Rust developers, it should also involve distrusting (and hence, personally auditing) the compiler, not least of all since a lot of the same people fall into both categories.